# How do I load a custom blade view at run time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

If I want to load a view from a custom folder at run time, I'm not sure how to do it.

I know I can add a permanent alternative to my view to the `paths` value in the config/view.php file.  However I have tried adding to this at run time just before calling with no success

eg.

```
Config::set(['views.paths' => 'my/custom/path']);
return view('bladeinmycustompath');
```

this doesnt work.  I have also tried using a full path to no avail.

Is there an easy way to render a specific blade file or add a custom path at run time.

I know I can simply add the path to the view.php file at design time but I dont want tot do this.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you let us know why a custom path for the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
public function loadCustomView()
{
    // Add the custom view path for this request
    View::addLocation('/path/to/your/custom/views');

    return view('customview'); // The view name without the .blade.php extension
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  Easy once you know how.